# How to theme/style the title bar in gnome-3?

Tags: css, themes, gnome-3

I am trying to create a theme for Gnome 3, but I am running into a bit of an issue with styling the title bar.  I am using the following CSS in my attempt to style the bars, but it only applies to windows that utilize a `GtkHeaderBar` to override the title bar.

```
headerbar {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset -1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(109, 179, 242, 0.5) 0%, rgba(84, 163, 238, 0.5) 50%, rgba(54, 144, 240, 0.5) 51%, rgba(30, 105, 222, 0.5) 100%);
  padding: 0 5px;
}

headerbar:backdrop {
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  border-bottom: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #C1C1C1 0%, #B1B1B1 50%, #A2A2A2 51%, #8B8B8B 100%);
}

/* Window Body */
window {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset -1px -1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(109, 179, 242, 0.5) 0%, rgba(84, 163, 238, 0.5) 50%, rgba(54, 144, 240, 0.5) 51%, rgba(30, 105, 222, 0.5) 100%);
  padding: 5px;
}

window:backdrop {
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  border-top: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #C1C1C1 0%, #B1B1B1 50%, #A2A2A2 51%, #8B8B8B 100%);
}

window > box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  background-image: none;
}
```

It appears that the window manager is using the styling information from the last loaded theme instead of the CSS I am providing.  I am switching themes by running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "<theme name"`.

This is what the title bar is supposed to look like (applied to a different window)
[image: Picture of theme applied properly]

This is what a `gtk3-demo` window looks like when switching to my theme after `Ambiance`
[image: Picture of theme with "ambiance"]

This is what a `gtk3-demo` window looks like when switching to my theme after `Adwaita`
[image]

My conclusion from this is that there is a separate set of css nodes or classes that are separate from `headerbar`, although none of the suggestions I have found online such as using `.header-bar` have lead to any success.  I attempted to inspect the css node hierarchy by launching the interactive debugger with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive gtk3-demo`, but the node hierarchy viewer ends at the `window` node, which does not include the title bar.

What is the proper way to style the title bar for themes in `gnome-3`?  Is there a master list of css nodes somewhere that could be used for reference?

**Edit:** I just came across and tried the `decoration` tag, but it seems to have the same issue as `headerbar`, where it does not effect windows without a `GtkHeaderBar` element.

**Edit 2:** It would now seem that my issue is not necessarily with the CSS I have created.  As a last ditch effort to try and induce any change in the title bars, I created a rule `* { color: #00ff00; background-color: #ff0000; background-image: none}` but it had no effect on the titles.  I am now beginning to think the default title bar is styled somewhere other than the application css, possibly in another folder under the `~/.themes/xyz/` directory.  Currently I have copied my entire CSS into both the `gtk-3.0` and `gtk-3.20` folders, but it doesn't seem to change anything.  This is a tree of my theme.  Are there required files missing from this?

```
.
├── gtk-3.0
│   └── gtk.css
├── gtk-3.20
│   └── gtk.css
└── index.theme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by forgetting to install the User Themes extension in `gnome-tweak-tool`.  Because the title bar for some applications is provided by the application itself, the theme applied to them, but other programs relied on the shell to provide the title bar, and were therefore left without a style.